# HTTP Status 404 - tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am building a spring + hibernate application. I'm getting a 404 error, when I run the project. The compiler does not show any error messages, it indicates that the application server (tomcat 7) loads the servlet, but does not display the root page indicated in the controller class.

Help please......

Config.....
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="langS.com" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.langS.model.Employee</value>
                <value>com.langS.EmployeeBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>`
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class NewController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeHome(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addEmployeeRecord(){
        return "addEmployee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployeesPage(){
        return "employeesList";
    }
}
```

web.xml

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: can you access your server like: localhost:8080?

Comment: Yes I can. I have tried accessing it in 3 ways, deploying the project, running it in eclipse, and my chrome browser.

Comment: Please verify your URL again, note: your web name is case sensitive.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Spring3HibernateApp/

Answer (score 0):

[404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means, that your tomcat server is getting the request, but does not now how to process the given request path.

In other words you have a bug in your URL or your configuration does not what you want it to do.

We need your configuration and desired URL to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you map the dispatcher servlet only to *.html, but you map you Controllers without using the .html suffix.

To make it work, either map you controller differently, ie :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcomeHome(){
    return "index";
}
```

OR (and what I would do) :
Map you dispatcher servlet to all requests in web.xml :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then if you want to call your application with a url looking like this :

```
http://somehost:someport/YourApplication/
```

Then you'll need to map some controller method like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
  // your code here
}
```

This way, calling `http://somehost:someport/YourApplication/` OR `http://somehost:someport/YourApplication/index` will result in the same controller method being called.

Comment: I have mapped it, I want it to first load the the index page

Comment: I don't see that mapping in the question.  Can you also show your dispatcher servlet mapping ? (in web.xml)
If you explicitly call http://somehost:someport/YourApplication/index , do you see your index page ?

Comment: When I explicitly call it in the address bar of the browser, after the server has started, i still get a 404 error. Please see above the question at the beginning, i posted 2 pieces of code

Comment: Maybe we could help more if you show us your servlet mapping (web.xml)

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer consequently.  Hope it help.